# Cannot click button on UIScrollview Objective - C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

Can not detect click some UIButton on UIScrollview. I described my problem in image description.

CODE :

```
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews { 
    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews]; 
    CGFloat scrollViewHeight = 0.0f; 
    for (UIView* view in _vContain.subviews) { 
        scrollViewHeight += view.frame.size.height; 
    } 
    [_svContain setContentSize:(CGSizeMake(_svContain.frame.size.width, scrollViewHeight + 50))]; 
}
```

[image]

Comment: You mean just the last button not working?

Comment: set the scrolling range of scrollView until the last `uicomponent` using `setContentView`  method.

Comment: Yes. Last button can not working when click. I added contentsize for UIScrollView

Comment: @DuyDoan show some code regarding your issue..

Comment: - (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews{
    
    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];
    CGFloat scrollViewHeight = 0.0f;
    for (UIView* view in _vContain.subviews)
    {
        scrollViewHeight += view.frame.size.height;
    }
    
    [_svContain setContentSize:(CGSizeMake(_svContain.frame.size.width, scrollViewHeight + 50))];
}

Comment: your problem must be existing here `scrollViewHeight + 50`, you need to set content size until the last button like:  `_svContain setContentSize:(CGSizeMake(_svContain.frame.size.width, lastbBtn.frame.origin.y+lastbBtn.frame.size.height +10 ))];`

Comment: Sorry but  I have added all the heights of the view. Please see for loop in my code

Answer (score 3):

Please set `ContentSize` of your `UIScrollView`.
Do it like this :

```
scroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(ScreenWidth, btn.frame.origin.y+btn.frame.size.height +10);
```

set your `UIScrollview` height like i show you in your image.

[image]

Comment: I added contentsize for UIScrollView but can not solve anything

Comment: make sure that your scrollview height is end at your bottom view Y axis.
your bottom view cannot overlap your scrollview

Comment: Suresuper viewWillLayoutSubviews];
    CGFloat scrollViewHeight = 0.0f;
    for (UIView* view in _vContain.subviews)
    {
        scrollViewHeight += view.frame.size.height;
    }
    
    [_svContain setContentSize:(CGSizeMake(_svContain.frame.size.width, scrollViewHeight + 50))];

Comment: Please decrease your scrollview height

Comment: please check now i updated my answer, i hope it will work

Comment: I set new height for UIScrollView but not OK. I added _vContain.clipsToBounds = YES; and then I can not see end button

Comment: Please see this image   https://gyazo.com/99f675129ce18500132a124701029624

Comment: this is not contentsize problem. problem is in sconstraint

Comment: set your bottom margin from scrollview